# Как вычислить, сколько пропущенных дней в календаре?

Tags: javascript, дата

Есть календарь, в нём также есть дни недели.
У меня получилось заполнять массив с днями, в зависимости от месяца.

Но возникла проблема: нужно как-то заполнить пустые места в календаре, как спереди, так и сзади. Пример на приложенном скриншоте.

У меня получается получить пропущенные дни сзади таким образом:

```
let dObj = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 1)
let blankDay = dObj.getDay()
blankDay = (blankDay === 0) ? 7 : blankDay
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как вычислить пропущенные дни спереди?

Comment: Cзади как раз сложнее, а что сложного заполнить спереди? Обычный цикл с 1 по...  (7-номер_дня_недели)+7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось довольно просто:

```
let days = []
let dObj = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 1)
let firstDay = new Date(dObj.getFullYear(), dObj.getMonth(), 1)
let dayOfWeek = firstDay.getDay()

let addDays = (current, days) => {
      let temp = new Date(current)
      temp.setDate(current.getDate() + days)
      return temp
}

let targetDate = addDays(firstDay, -dayOfWeek)
for (let i = 0; i < 7 * 5; i++) {
      let calendarDay = addDays(targetDate, i)
      days.push({
        date: calendarDay.getDate(),
        fullDate: calendarDay.toLocaleDateString(),
    })
```